# Terraform "azurerm_storage_share" file share gives 403

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

From vsts release definition terraform task, create rg, vnet, subnet with:

```
service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
```

Then public ip, nsg, vnic

Then create az storage account, with:

```
network_rules {
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = ["${azurerm_subnet.main.id}"]
}
```

when try to create a storage share:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "someshare" { ...
```

this gives a 403. Even giving the service principal owner permissions makes no difference. Resorted to using a powershell follow on script as another task to add the file shares. Can terraform do this?

Comment: Interestingly, if I remove the "network_rules" from the storage account block, then the file share gets created. However, I can't then go on to add a network rule to the storage account with the file share. This is starting to feel like a bug or limitation of the terraform engine.

Comment: What is the full 403 error? This message is typically returned by the Azure API and can point you in the right direction.